# How can i open popup window in ExtJS with formpanel only

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

I have the Form panel which constains the form with fields.

Now on click of button , i am opening the window and then adding form as item in window like this

```
win = new Ext.Window({
    title: 'Add',
    layout: 'fit',
    autoScroll: true,
    y: 120,
    width: 600,
    height: 600,
    modal: true,
    closeAction: 'hide',
    items: [formpanel]
});
win.show();
```

Now this shows two windows one shows the main window title `Add` and border and then one more frame of formpanel with title and borders.

Is there any way so that window only conatins form title and border but not windows title and border and background

Its like showuing only formPanle as popup , rather than formpanel inside window

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make it as `floating` and `closable` config to achieve your task.

`closable:true`  will help you to appear cross button at corner as you require.

```
var myForm = new Ext.form.Panel({
    width: 500,
    height: 400,
    title: 'Foo',
    floating: true,
    closable : true
});
myForm.show();
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: Did you try it @user191542

Comment: Thats great @user191542. Happy coding.

Comment: How can i make the form always appear at center of screen

Comment: please make it an new request with updated code @user191542. it will be useful for other to track it and solve their problem.

Answer (score 3):

`floating: true` automatically fits the form in the center. If not you can use center() method of form.panel.

```
var myForm = new Ext.form.Panel({
    width: 500,
    height: 400,
    title: 'Form Window',
    floating: true,
    closable : true
});
myForm.show();
```

Below call will make the form in center.

```
myForm.center();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can configure your form as floating:

```
var f = new Ext.form.Panel({
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
    title: 'Foo',
    floating: true
});
f.show();
```

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1dj)

Comment: thanks but how can i have cross button at the corner

Comment: Add a close tool to the form definition.

Comment: How can i make the form always appear at center of screen

Comment: You can use myForm.center() method to make the form center of screen. For reference see my answer.